# Fresh install of Ubuntu Server - Will raid (MDADM) be detected without losing data?

Tags: boot, server, raid, mdadm

hoping you can help me. My server's current boot drive appears to be dead. I can't boot. Internally i have four drives. The last three were set up as raid 5 with mdadm. The drive in slot 1 was just a standard storage drive with nothing on it that i don't already have backed up elsewhere.

my main question is, if i perform a fresh ubuntu server install onto drive 1, will i be able to detect my raid (drive 2-4) without loosing all of the data stored. sorry if i'm not specific or technical enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the server, yes, it is possible to recover the MD RAID array. There are plenty of guides to do this online if you search for `mdadm` and `reassemble` which are the right words.

Essentially you want to first check that the array is there on boot by looking at `cat /proc/mdstat` which should reveal the `/dev/mdX` name, and which devices are in the array, and what kinda of array. For example, this is an active RAID 5 array on `/dev/md0` comprising partitions across drives `/dev/sdd4`, `/dev/sdb2`, `/dev/sda0`, and `/dev/sdc1`.

```shell
alan@earth:~$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid5 sdd[4] sdb[2] sda[0] sdc[1]
      8790402048 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 8/22 pages [32KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Yours may look different, but that's roughly what you should get.

If you don't, you can use the following command to scan (but this shouldn't be necessary as I believe Ubuntu will scan on boot).

`sudo mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose`

Once you have the device name, you can test mounting it with a simple `sudo mkdir /mnt/array && sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/array` and check out the files in `/mnt/array`. If that's all good you can add an entry to your `/etc/fstab` to mount on boot.

Comment: Thankyou, that's exactly what i needed to hear. I know my array was set on sdc, sdd and sde. Which are located on internal drives 2-4. My original boot drive was on an external, I had used to migrate an older system. I never got around to cloning it to my internal drive 1. That drive is now dead.
Thank you for your help